How can I implement a "Flash in" animation?
Currently I have a div that has the class "hidden" (css, display: none). I want it to add the class "full-size" after a set ammount of time with javascript. However, how can I implement a "flash in" function?
setTimeout(fade_out, 28000);

function fade_out() {
    $("#interval").fadeOut().empty();
}

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $("#main").fadeIn().addClass('full-size');
}, 28000);

Instead of "fadeIn()", is there something similar that gives a "White flash in" animation where it flashes you with a white color and then the white color fades out to reveal "#main"?
Sorry if this request is unreasonable, this'll be my first time asking a question instead of using AI!! Figured that it might be a good opportunity :D
I tried searching on google but really couldn't find what I was searching for.
The best I got was a "repetitivily flashing, blinking" animation:
$("#someElement").fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);

Which, unluckily, it isn't what I was searching for :(

This question is similar to: How do you make an element "flash" in jQuery. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is there a reason for using jquery? This sounds like a simple implementation using CSS but I'd like to be certain that I understand exactly what is required. You want the viewport to go white suddenly and then gradually the white fades away to reveal something new. Is that right?

Ppl with epilepsy will love this /s.

Nono it really isnt a weapon against epileptic people (╥﹏╥)

I mentioned a snippet of code found from "How do you make an element "flash" in jQuery" in my question, sadly that isnt the code i was searching for. Thank you very much tho!!

And yes, A Haworth, that is exactly what im searching for!! I dont mind the usage of CSS, ofcourse :)

You can use CSS animation to this. Test the sample code. Hope it be helpful.
Change to flash once by editing CSS. animation:flasher 2s 1 linear; infinite --> 1
Change speed by editing CSS. animation:flasher 0.5s 1 linear;  2s --> 0.5s


function stopFlash() {
  document.getElementById("flasher0").style.animation = "none";
}

function startFlash() {
  document.getElementById("flasher0").style.animation = "flasher 2s infinite linear";
}
  @keyframes flasher {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:200px;position:relative;">
  <div id="flasher0" style="animation:flasher 2s infinite linear;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>

  the main content. You can change to flash once by editing CSS. animation:flasher 2s 1 linear; infinite --> 1 You can change speed by editing CSS. animation:flasher 0.5s 1 linear; 2s --> 0.5s

</div>

<button onclick="startFlash();">click to start flasher.</button>
<button onclick="stopFlash();">click to stop flasher.</button>




Perfect!! This is exactly what i was searching for!! What I needed: "An animation, which flashes the screen with white, before fading away to reveal new content". And i got that from this code simply by removing the "infinite" value as you suggested!! Thank you very much ♡⸜(˶˃ ᵕ ˂˶)⸝♡

If you really want to use JavaScript, use the Web Animation API, we don't even have to use classes. It's hard to be more concise than that.


elem.animate([{opacity:0},{opacity:1}],{duration:1000,iterations:Infinity})
<h1 id="elem">Fade-in Blink effect!</h1>



